# Strange MySQL AVG() anomaly NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, null

What I'am doing :

```
create table sample (id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,name varchar(255),marks INT(10));

insert into sample (name,marks) VALUES('sam',10);
insert into sample (name,marks) VALUES('sam',20);
insert into sample (name,marks) VALUES('sam',NULL);
insert into sample (name,marks) VALUES('sam',NULL);
insert into sample (name,marks) VALUES('sam',30);

select AVG(marks) from sample GROUP BY(name);
```

**OUTPUT I EXPECTED :**

> AVG = (10+20+30)/5 = 12

**OUTPUT OF MYSQL :**

> AVG = (10+20+30)/3 = 20

Ideally what i wanted is that MYSQL should get the sum of 5 rows and divide it by 5 , but it only divides by 3 (the non-NULL rows)

Why does this occur and what can i do to get the correct AVG ie 60/5 ?
PS: I cannot make the marks field NOT NULL , in my db design the marks field is allowed to be NULL.

Thank you

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is the correct behavior, because in SQL, `NULL` is not the same as the number `0`.
This might surprise some non-english speakers, because in many languages "null" is equivalent to "zero".

Conceptually, [`NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html) refers to an “unknown value” and as such it is treated differently from other values. That is why [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) like [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) ignore `NULL`s.

[`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) calculates the average over all "known" values only. (= that are *not* NULL)

From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html):

> Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values.

Also, read about the concept of `NULL`s in [Section "3.3.4.6 Working with NULL Values"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html)  of the MySQL manual.

To get what you want, you might do

```
SELECT AVG(COALESCE(marks, 0))
FROM sample 
GROUP BY name;
```

[`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns the next argument for calculations if the value is `NULL` or  passes through the value otherwise.

---

There are more common misunderstandings regarding the concept of `NULL`. These are also explained  in [Section "5.5.3 Problems with NULL"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-null.html) of the manual:

> - In SQL, the `NULL` value is never true in comparison to any other value, even `NULL`. An expression that contains `NULL` always produces a `NULL` value unless otherwise indicated in the documentation for the operators and functions involved in the expression.
>    i.e.: `NULL == 0` results in NULL instead of `true`. Also `NULL == NULL` results in NULL, instead of true.
> - To search for column values that are `NULL`, you cannot use an `expr = NULL` test. To look for `NULL` values, you must use the `IS NULL` test.
> - When using `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, or `ORDER BY`, all `NULL` values are regarded as equal.
> - When using `ORDER BY`, `NULL` values are presented first, or last if you specify `DESC` to sort in descending order.
> - For some data types, MySQL handles NULL values specially. If you insert `NULL` into a `TIMESTAMP` column, the current date and time is inserted.
> - If you insert `NULL` into an integer or floating-point column that has the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute, the next number in the sequence is inserted.
> - A column that has a `UNIQUE` key defined can still contain multiple `NULL` values.

Comment: thanks @kaii , that solution helped , i was under the impression mySQL performed the AVG like = sum/(nos of columns in the result)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
select avg(case marks when null then 0 else marks end) from sample group by name;
```

Or try and avoid nulls in the table ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this instead:

```
SELECT SUM(marks) / COUNT(name)
FROM sample 
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the normal behaviour, since NULL is not zero. How do you make the average of 5 + NULL? So MySQL is taking only the rows that can be averaged.

Appart from the correct answers other users have already given you, you can also use the COALESCE function, which returns the first non-NULL value you specify in the list, so you can replace the NULL one with the one you like:

```
    SELECT AVG(COALESCE(marks,0)) FROM sample GROUP BY(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
       avg(CASE WHEN price IS NULL THEN 0 else price END), 
       avg(CASE WHEN discount IS NULL THEN 0 else discount END), 
       avg(CASE WHEN total IS NULL THEN 0 else total END) 
FROM pet;
```