# how to insert average of a query into mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get average of latency for each items that holds into two separate mysql table. Let me more clarify that I have two mysql tables as below,

table: monitor_servers

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| server_id | label           |
+-----------+-----------------+
|         1 | a.com           |
|         2 | b.com           |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

table: monitor_servers_uptime

```
+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
| servers_uptime_id | server_id | latency   |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                 1 |         1 | 0.4132809 |
|                 3 |         1 | 0.4157769 |
|                 6 |         1 | 0.4194210 |
|                 9 |         1 | 0.4140880 |
|                12 |         2 | 0.4779439 |
|                15 |         2 | 0.4751789 |
|                18 |         2 | 0.4762829 |
|                22 |         2 | 0.4706681 |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Basically, each domains associated with the same id_number in both tables. While I am running the query below, getting average of each items.

```
select monitor_servers.label, avg(monitor_servers_uptime.latency)
from monitor_servers,monitor_servers_uptime  
where monitor_servers.server_id = monitor_servers_uptime.server_id 
group by monitor_servers.server_id;
```

The query ended up,

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| label               | avg(monitor_servers_uptime.latency) |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| a.com               |                       0.41393792995 |
| b.com               |                       0.47551423171 |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

My questions are doing am i in wright way while getting average  of the each items and how can i insert new average result of each items into a new column on table monitor_servers ? And also what happens if some of latency rows are NULL ?

**Edit : What i am trying to achieve in one query result is **

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+
| server_id | label    |  avg.            |
+-----------+----------+------------------+
|         1 | a.com    | 0.41393792995    |
|         2 | b.com    | 0.47551423171    |
+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you want to write the data to another table? Wouldn't that be redundant?

Comment: i want to save latest average value of each item into extra field such as new column named 'avg'

Answer (score 0):

1. Your calculation seems to be correct.
2. You could add another column to the monitor_servers using sql:

`ALTER TABLE monitor_servers ADD avg_latency DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL`

For doing the AVG calculation check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14020948/4634317) answer.