# Different Counts in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, null, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this:

```
-----------------------
|  Name   | Date      |
-----------------------
| John    | July      |
| Carl    | August    |
| John    | July      |
| Robert  | August    |
| Carl    | September |
| John    | August    |
| Carl    | August    |
| John    | July      |
| Robert  | September |
| Carl    | August    |
-----------------------
```

I would like to count the names divided by month.

```
SELECT Name, 
COUNT(IF(`Date` = 'July',1,0)) AS July,
COUNT(IF(`Date` = 'August',1,0)) AS August,
COUNT(IF(`Date` = 'September',1,0)) AS September,
COUNT(*) AS All FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

I tried this query, but the count values ​​are all the same

Comment: And what is the result?

Comment: In MySQL `COUNT(IF(Date = 'July',1,0))` can also be `COUNT(Date = 'July')` it does not matter.  mind the backticks tho around Date

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql: is it possible to 'SUM IF' or to 'COUNT IF'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075505/mysql-is-it-possible-to-sum-if-or-to-count-if)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
  SUM(IF(`month` = 'July',1,0)) AS July,
  SUM(IF(`month` = 'August',1,0)) AS August,
  SUM(IF(`month` = 'September',1,0)) AS September,
  COUNT(*)  FROM test
GROUP BY name;
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13075582/1688441

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this happens is simple: `COUNT()` just counts the *occurances of values*. (= how many values are in the dataset?)

Looking at it this way, `0` is just another value like `1` is, too.

You can either do:

```
SELECT Name, 
COUNT(IF(`Date` = 'July', 1, NULL)) AS July,
COUNT(IF(`Date` = 'August', 1, NULL)) AS August,
COUNT(IF(`Date` = 'September', 1, NULL)) AS September,
COUNT(*) AS All FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

This works because aggregate functions like `COUNT()` ignore `NULL` values.

Or, as others replied, you might just `SUM()` all the `1` values:

```
SELECT Name, 
SUM(`Date` = 'July') AS July,
SUM(`Date` = 'August') AS August,
SUM(`Date` = 'September') AS September,
COUNT(*) AS All FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

This is written shorter, because the evaluation `field = value` already returns `1` if it matches or 0 otherwise. No need to wrap an `IF()` around to do exactly the same.

Comment: For more info about the common misunderstanding of `NULL` vs `0` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020924/strange-mysql-avg-anomaly-null-values/14020948#14020948

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way you can try this. *condition aggregate function* with bool (0 or 1)

```
SELECT Name, 
    SUM(`Date` = 'July') AS July,
    SUM(`Date` = 'August') AS August,
    SUM(`Date` = 'September') AS September,
    COUNT(*) AS All 
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` counts non-null values, try [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

```
SELECT Name, 
SUM(IF(`Date` = 'July',1,0)) AS July,
SUM(IF(`Date` = 'August',1,0)) AS August,
SUM(IF(`Date` = 'September',1,0)) AS September,
COUNT(*) AS All FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT Name, Date, Count(*) as Count FROM table GROUP BY Name,Date`

It should return something like this:

```
| Name  | Date      | Count |
-----------------------------
| Carl  | August    |   3   |
| Carl  | September |   1   |
| John  | July      |   3   |
| John  | August    |   1   |
| Robert| September |   1   |
| Rober | August    |   1   |
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0a483/7).

Comment: Tried your answer on the test data here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0a483/6

Comment: If you see OP attempt he want one single row by each user

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza that's true, but he way to do this is very inefficient, maybe he can work with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`count` counts values that are not `null` - including zeroes. With those `if`s, you can use a `sum` to emulate a `count` - you'll effectively be counting the values that are `1`s:

```
SELECT Name, 
SUM(IF(`Date` = 'July',1,0)) AS July,
SUM(IF(`Date` = 'August',1,0)) AS August,
SUM(IF(`Date` = 'September',1,0)) AS September,
SUM(*) AS All FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: @Horez `SUM(IF(Date = 'July',1,0))` can also be rewritten als `SUM(Date = 'July')`  it does not matter. mind the backticks tho around Date

Answer (score 0):

```
select date, count(*) 
from table1
group by date
```

Should give you something like

```
|DATE       |Count(*)|
----------------------
|August     |    5   |
|July       |    3   |
|September  |    2   |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0a483/2

Comment: That's not the expected result. He want to get name and date count. See my answer below.

Comment: You might be right. The expected result was not as clear from the initial question. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out. I tried your answer and I commented the SQLFiddle on it.

Comment: @EliasSoares Actually OP said `I would like to count the names divided by month.` And I understand it that like this too,