# Average of 4 columns, with random null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an employee table with 4 types of bonuses.  I want to add up the four bonuses for each employee and find the average.  Some employees aren't eligible for bonuses, so that type of bonus shouldn't count against their average.  Besides making fun of the database design (which isn't my fault), does anyone have a creative way of ignoring the NULL values when calculating that average?

The only employee with the correct average in the table below, is Employee1.

```
SELECT title, (IFNULL(level1,0)+IFNULL(level2,0)+IFNULL(level3,0)+IFNULL(level4,0))/4 as avglevel, level1, level2, level3, level4
FROM test;
Title       avglevel    level1  level2  level3  level4
Employee1   2500.0000   1000    2000    3000    4000
Employee2   2250.0000   NULL    2000    3000    4000
Employee3   2000.0000   1000    NULL    3000    4000
Employee4   1750.0000   1000    2000    NULL    4000
Employee5   1500.0000   1000    2000    3000    NULL
```

I found this item, but it really only covers the AVG function and not dividing by the number of columns, except when one of those columns is NULL.
[Strange MySQL AVG() anomaly NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020924/strange-mysql-avg-anomaly-null-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange MySQL AVG() anomaly NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020924/strange-mysql-avg-anomaly-null-values)

Answer (score 2):

Because of your current table design, you have the need to perform aggregation operations over *columns*, rather than rows.  MySQL in general has strong support for aggregation across rows/records, but less so columns.  If you are opening to changing your table design, then the `AVG` function can already handle this problem as it comes out of the box.  Consider storing your table as:

```
Title     | level | amount
Employee2 | 1     | NULL
Employee2 | 2     | 2000
Employee2 | 3     | 3000
Employee2 | 4     | 4000
```

That is, store each level value, per employee, on a separate record.  Then you may easily compute the correct average using:

```
SELECT
    title,
    AVG(amount) AS avglevel
FROM test
GROUP BY
    title;
```

### Demo

The `AVG` function will already ignore `NULL` values by default, and so the sum will be normalized by a record count which does not include those records having `NULL`.

**Edit:**

After setting up the demo, it seems that you *do* want to normalize the average using all levels, even if the amount be `NULL`.  In this case, we can take the sum divided by the count:

```
SELECT
    title,
    SUM(amount) / COUNT(*) AS avglevel
FROM test
GROUP BY
    title;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using case when for you denominator

```
SELECT title, 
(level1+level2+level3+level4)/(case when level1 is not null then 1 end+
case when level2 is not null then 1 end+case when level3 is not null then 1 end+case when level4 is not null then 1 end) as avglevel, 
level1, level2, level3, level4
FROM test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single expression.  MySQL has some built in capabilities that makes this a bit simpler:

```
SELECT title, 
       (COALESCE(level1, 0) + COALESCE(level2, 0) + COALESCE(level3, 0) + COALESCE(level4, 0)
       ) /
       ( (level1 is not null) + (level2 is not null) +
         (level3 is not null) + (level4 is not null)
       ) as avglevel,
      level1, level2, level3, level4
FROM test;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using case when

```
 SELECT title, 
(IFNULL(level1,0)+IFNULL(level2,0)+IFNULL(level3,0)+IFNULL(level4,0))/
(4-(case when level1 is null then 1 else 0 end)-(case when level2 is null then 1 else 0 end)-
(case when level3 is null then 1 else 0 end)- (case when level4 is null then 1 else 0 end) ) as avglevel,
level1, level2, level3, level4
FROM test;
```